# Differential notation in definition of line integrals of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Sorry for the bad title, couldn't think of anything better.

Just as I though I'd finally understood the differential notations and what meant what, comes this in my textbook.

So the chapter is line integrals of a function. I've gotten through the formal definition and everything but the outline is this:

The curve is parametrized with $r(t)=(x(t), y(t), z(t))$. In order to define the integral we've first split the interval in which $t$ lies $[a, b]$ using $t_j$ such that $a=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=b$, where then we denoted the points $A_j$ as $A_j =r(t_j)$. We use $\triangle s_j$ to denote the length of the curve from point $A_{j-1}$ to point $A_j$. We use $\triangle t_j$ to denote $t_j - t_{j-1}$ We've shown that $\triangle s_j = \int_{t_{j-1}}^{t_j}||r'(t)||dt$ (the usual formula for arc length).

After the actual definition of the line integral came the confusing part. Goes like this (I'm mostly quoting now):

> We use the notation: $$dr:=r'(t)dt =(x'(t), y'(t), z'(t))dt = (dx, dy,
> dz)$$

As far as I can see this is simply because, looking at $x, y$ and $z$ as functions of $t$ we know that $x'(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$, $y'(t)=\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $z'(t) = \frac{dz}{dt}$ which, of course, means that $x'(t)dt = dx$, $y'(t)dt = dy$ and $z'(t)dt = dz$. So that's fine. Also this:

> We notice that for arbitrary $c_j \in [t_{j-1}, t_j]$ we can
>   approximate the length of the curve $\triangle s_j$ as $||r'(c_j)||\triangle t_j$
>   since: $$|\triangle s_j - ||r'(c_j)||\triangle t_j| =
>  \bigg|\int_{t_{j-1}}^{tj}||r'(t)||dt - ||r'(c_j)||\triangle t_j \bigg|
>  = \bigg| ||r'(\alpha_j)||\triangle t_j - ||r'(c_j)||\triangle t_j \bigg| = \triangle t_j\bigg|||r'(\alpha_j)|| - ||r'(c_j)|| \bigg| $$

The mid-value theorem for integrals is used at one point, no problem there. I suppose that the argument here is that as we divide the interval $[a, b]$ into smaller sub-intervals (as $\triangle t_j$  gets smaller), the difference between the actual curve length between two points $\triangle s_j$ and what we said we could approximate it with gets smaller.

So the conclusion from this is that we can approximate $\triangle s_j$ as $||r'(c_j)||\triangle t_j$ for some $c_j \in [t_{j-1}, t_j]$

And finally, the part that confuses me:

> We also notice that $r'(t)dt = dr(t)(e)$ where $e$ is the basis unit
>   vector of $\mathbb{R}$, therefore we can approximate $\triangle s_j$
>   as $$||dr(c_j)(\triangle t_j e)||$$

This sentence has got me questioning everything I know about differentials and calculus in general. Above it's mentioned that 
$dr = (dx, dy, dz)$. And now we have the expression $dr(t)(e)$. Which bracket means what? Does $dr$ act as an operator or a vector? Is it regular multiplication or a scalar product? If $r'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t), z'(t))$ how can it possibly then be that $r'(t) = dr(t)(e)$, whatever it meant anyway.

It makes so little sense to me that I'm not even sure what to ask. So, could anyone help out? Thanks.